# FormsAuthentication.Decrypt method returns null value in Server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Formauthentication Encrypt and Decrypt method Working fine locally 
but Formauthentication Decrypt method returns null value in server ,Can anyone help me please

Regards,
Manju

Comment: How do you know it returns null?  Could you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you encrypted the value, more than likely the encryption key between your dev machine and your server do not match (found in machine.config), resulting in a failed decryption on the server. If you encrypt the value on the server and replace the hashed value in your config with that new string, you should be back up and running.